# Attempting to show logo using 'content' from CSS

Tags: html, css

I have tried to show a logo on the header of my website but have been unsuccessful despite trying a number of times. I have tried to set the logo using HTML  syntax as well as using the:

```
.div 
{ 
content: url (...jpg);
}
```

Both have returned a small box in the header with a question mark in it. I have no idea why i am having issues with getting it to display the logo.

this is what it looks like at the moment:

[image: Logo in header]

and this is the code i have in css:

```
.logo::before {
  content: url(new-bcu-logo.jpg);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-slide-dropdown">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

                </button>

                <div class="logo navbar-brand">Student Dashboard</div>
            </div>
```

Any ideas how I can get this logo to display. Much appreciated.

Comment: Where is `new-bcu-logo.jpg` relative to the CSS?

Comment: Its currently in the main file folder where the html files are. I have some hard coded css at the top of the html page using the <style> tags

Comment: Have you looked at the resources tab of your browser's developer tools, to see whether the image is found at all? Because I suspect the wrong path, or a typo of some kind in the file name.

Comment: Try put it in quotes. So it looks like this: 

`content: url('new-bcu-logo.jpg');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure `new-bcu-logo.jpg` is in the same folder where you css files is, if you use inline style make sure that image is in the same folder as the html file.

Comment: thank you for your response. I can confirm the image file is in the same folder as the html file which is why i am so confused as to why it won't display the image

Comment: try another image, that image might be broken.

Comment: Thanks guys. Its working great now. was a problem with the picture.